# 'this' of a Class instance is changed by addEventListener()

Tags: javascript, class

There is a 'this' problem. I meant an instance by `this`, but it actually means `<button>` element. How can I add a value to the instance's array?

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
    this.arr = [];
  }

  addValue(event) {
    console.log(this); // 'this' is <button>add</button>
    this.arr.push('added'); // Error!
    console.log(this.arr);
  }
}

const c = new MyClass();
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', c.addValue);
```

```html
<button>add</button>
```

Comment: btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => c.addValue(event));

Comment: Or `btn.addEventListener('click', c.addValue.bind(c));` (which avoids creating a closure with captures - and you can `removeEventListener` too - whereas with inline `=>`-style callbacks you can't un-register listeners.

Comment: Or use `addValue = (event) => {`…`}` in the field definition. See [How does the "this" keyword work, and when should it be used?](/q/3127429/4642212).